# Node && Mongodb findOne is not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Cannot read property 'title' of null !!! Showing  While rendring the findone.ejs file.. But The first one in db is showing perfectly..

```
app.get('/books/:title', (req, res) => {
  db.collection("Book")
    .findOne({ 'title': req.params.title }, function(err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;

      res.render('findone.ejs', { Book: result});
    });
})
```

Database Schema:
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var Schema   = mongoose.Schema;

```
var BookSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    author: String,
    category: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Book', BookSchema);
```

Mongo Database.

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5a14a5edf6fe123247b890f3"
    },
    "title": "ttt",
    "author": "ttttt",
    "category": "tttttttttttt"
}

{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5a14a5f2f6fe123247b890f4"
    },
    "title": "tttt",
    "author": "ttttt",
    "category": "ttttttttttttttttttttttttttt"
}

{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5a154e4bff45fe2c9035f9da"
    },
    "title": "hello ",
    "author": "rabbani",
    "category": "how are you"
}
```

Comment: Then that means the query is not matching any documents or there are no documents in the collection with that specific title. When you log `req.params.title` before the query, what do you get?

Comment: it is showing the title i want to compare && that   i am giving on the link. The first value of the database is showing with out any error ..

Comment: Can you add your ''Book" model code

Comment: Also I see you're using es6 and es5, consistency matters, you should refactor that.

Comment: @akinjide I have update the code And have a look on my database schema.

Comment: @RabbaniSarkar Can you also paste the error here, just so we can have more context.

Comment: try `/book/ttt` maybe there is no params

Comment: I thing error is occurring because req.params is undefined. Could you please add req.params value.

Comment: I am loging the result the output below 1 st value of my database is showing perfectlly but others is not working..                                  
    listening on 9090
    Your req.params is: ttt
    { _id: 5a14a5f2f6fe123247b890f4,
      title: 'ttt',
      author: 'ttttt',
      category: 'ttttttttttttttttttttttttttt' }
      Your req.params is: hello
      null

Comment: I'd suggest you `drop database or collection` and then `.trim` the `req.params.title` or just send back as `req.body`

Answer (score -3):

If you are using mongoose then you can import the schema like this

```
Book = mongoose.model('Book')
```

and query like this

```
Book.findOne({"title": title}, function(err, book) {
  //handle book
})
```

Of course you have to ensure that the title is unique.

Comment: @rabbani comment was `Cannot read property 'title' of null !!!` I'm sure he is importing the model

Comment: Doesn't that mean `req.params` is null?